# IPTables -L does not work properly

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

When I add

```
-A INPUT -p udp -j DROP
```

at the end of my `INPUT` Chain, if I then type `iptables -L` the list will stop displaying at the drop command.

Before that I am allowing SSH on tcp and some other stuff.

So why does it stop displaying the list?

Comment: perhaps you could provide us exact output so we can actually see what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a DNS lookup is blocking the output - try:

```
iptables -nL
```

Comment: lol! of course it does if you block UDP incomming - UDP is used for DNS queries.